# Displaying MySQL Data with Images in Table

Tags: php, html, mysqli, html-table

I have set up a table that displays data from my SQL database using

```
 $sql = "SELECT company_id, stk_buy, stk_sell FROM price";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
       echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Company</th><th>Buying Price</th><th>Selling Price</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["company_id"]."</td><td>".$row["stk_buy"]."</td><td>".$row["stk_sell"]."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
   } else {
       echo "0 results";
   }
```

I want to have images display in the Company column, different ones in each row.
Similar to: [image]
Is there a possible way of displaying images with my current html table setup or do I have to fetch each row to display images?

Comment: Just use the `<img src="">` with the exact source of that image. How you store your image?? Is it in the database. How you will find the image name??

Comment: @FrayneKonok Inserting it as such  `echo "<tr><td>".$row["company_id"]."</td><td><img src='img/1.png' style='width:175px;height:75px;'></img></td><td>".$row["stk_buy"]."</td><td>".$row["stk_sell"]."</td></tr>"; ` displays the image provided in the question. I want different images for each id

Comment: Yes... But you have to use different image name for each row. Where is your image names??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch the image name from the database, after fetching the images you need to put it inside a `<IMG src="">` tag.

The source of the image considering the `img` as you mention in the comment.

**SQL:** `$sql = "SELECT company_id, stk_buy, stk_sell FROM price";`

```
echo "<tr><td>".$row["company_id"]."</td><td><img src='img/".$row[company_id].".png' style='width:175px;height:75px;'/></td><td>".$row["stk_‌​buy"]."</td><td>".$r‌​ow["stk_sell"]."</td‌​></tr>";
```

Comment: So I can't fetch images from local source?

Comment: Sure! But how could you know which images for which row and what will be the name??

Comment: My current naming scheme is 1.png, 2.png, 3.png etc. Then 1.png for row 1 and so on

Comment: OK than its easy to control... Check the modified answer.

Answer (score 0):

In these query you have not gave the image coloum name.You have to assign image coloum name like this

```
$sql = "SELECT company_id,image(column name for image) stk_buy, stk_sell FROM price";
```

Comment: I was just going to use images from folder instead of database. Would it be easier to upload images to database instead?

Comment: yes it's easy to upload the image into database.You have to use it its easy and after that you fetch the image from database.

Answer (score 0):

First change your query to get image as well from table and then In your echo for table row, add one more td tag with img tag and src of the image to point the path where the image is stored. Something like

```
echo "<tr><td>".$row["company_id"]."</td><td><img src='./path-to-image/".$row["image-column-name"]."' width='100' height='100'/></td><td>".$row["stk_buy"]."</td><td>".$row["stk_sell"]."</td></tr>";
```

You can change width and height attributes value to what you want.